# Coverage report not published using Docker and pytest-azurepipelines

Tags: docker, azure-pipelines, pytest

In the Azure DevOps pipeline, running pytest in the docker container is not publishing the test coverage report.

`Warnings: Coverage XML was not created, skipping upload.`
[image]

**Dockerfile**

```
..
...

RUN pip install pytest pytest-azurepipelines pytest-cov
...
..
```

**azure-pipelines.yml**

```yaml
- task: Bash@3
  displayName: Run Python Tests
  inputs:
    targetType: "inline"
    script: |
      docker run --user "$(id -u):$(id -g)" -v "$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/data-science/app:/usr/src/app" "$(azure.acr.name).azurecr.io/project-name:$(branchName)" pytest tests/ --cov-report xml
```

**Pipeline Logs**

```bash
============================= test session starts ==============================
platform linux -- Python 3.7.13, pytest-7.1.2, pluggy-1.0.0
rootdir: /usr/src/app, configfile: pytest.ini
plugins: anyio-3.6.2, nunit-1.0.3, azurepipelines-1.0.4, cov-4.0.0
collected 13 items

tests/test_main.py ..                                                    [ 15%]
tests/abc****_tests/test_api.py ....                                  [ 46%]
tests/abc****_tests/test_abc.py .                                     [ 53%]
Result Attachments will be stored in LogStore
Run Attachments will be stored in LogStore
Failed to parse result files: System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not find file '/usr/src/app/test-output.xml'.
File name: '/usr/src/app/test-output.xml'
   at Interop.ThrowExceptionForIoErrno(ErrorInfo errorInfo, String path, Boolean isDirectory, Func`2 errorRewriter)
   at Microsoft.Win32.SafeHandles.SafeFileHandle.Open(String path, OpenFlags flags, Int32 mode)
   at System.IO.FileStream.OpenHandle(FileMode mode, FileShare share, FileOptions options)
   at System.IO.FileStream..ctor(String path, FileMode mode, FileAccess access, FileShare share, Int32 bufferSize, FileOptions options)
   at System.IO.FileStream..ctor(String path, FileMode mode, FileAccess access, FileShare share, Int32 bufferSize)
   at System.Xml.XmlDownloadManager.GetStream(Uri uri, ICredentials credentials, IWebProxy proxy, RequestCachePolicy cachePolicy)
   at System.Xml.XmlUrlResolver.GetEntity(Uri absoluteUri, String role, Type ofObjectToReturn)
   at System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.FinishInitUriString()
   at System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl..ctor(String uriStr, XmlReaderSettings settings, XmlParserContext context, XmlResolver uriResolver)
   at System.Xml.XmlReaderSettings.CreateReader(String inputUri, XmlParserContext inputContext)
   at System.Xml.XmlReader.Create(String inputUri, XmlReaderSettings settings)
   at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.TestClient.PublishTestResults.NUnitResultParser.ParseTestResultFile(TestRunContext runContext, String filePath)
   at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.TestClient.PublishTestResults.NUnitResultParser.<>c__DisplayClass1_0.<ParseTestResultFiles>b__0(String file)
   at System.Linq.Enumerable.SelectListIterator`2.MoveNext()
   at System.Linq.Enumerable.WhereEnumerableIterator`1.ToList()
   at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.TestClient.PublishTestResults.NUnitResultParser.ParseTestResultFiles(TestRunContext runContext, IList`1 resultFilePaths)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.Agent.Worker.TestResults.Parser.ParseFiles(IExecutionContext executionContext, TestRunContext testRunContext, List`1 testResultsFiles, ITestResultParser testResultParser)
##[warning]Coverage XML was not created, skipping upload.


------------ generated Nunit xml file: /usr/src/app/test-output.xml ------------
--------- generated xml file: /usr/src/app/tests/junit/test-output.xml ---------
============================= 13 passed in 10.16s ==============================
Async Command Start: Publish test results
Async Command End: Publish test results
Finishing: Run Python Tests
```

If you notice the XML file - `/usr/src/app/test-output.xml` is created later but the exception is raised before it was generated.

#### Update

The docker cp solution will get your coverage published in the pipeline but you won't be able to see the line-wise coverage in the UI. Here is what you get when you click on the module:
[image]

**References:**

- https://github.com/Azure/pytest-azurepipelines#running-in-docker

Comment: hi yardstick, could you share the latest status of your issue?

Answer (score 0):

You could use the `docker cp` command to copy the .xml file out like `&& docker cp mycontainer:/coverage.xml ~/Development/coverage.xml`

Another option is to use a volume, so something like `docker run -it -v ~/Development:/output testimage python -m pytest tests -v --cov=app --cov-report xml:/output/coverage.xml`

=========================================================

**Updated on 11/30**

I suppose that you need to generate your test result report into the format that azure devops pipeline could recognize first.

Check this doc for [generate python test report in to junit.xml](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/ecosystems/python?view=azure-devops#test-with-pytest-and-collect-coverage-metrics-with-pytest-cov)

```
- script: |
    pip install pytest pytest-azurepipelines
    pip install pytest-cov
    pytest --doctest-modules --junitxml=junit/test-results.xml --cov=. --cov-report=xml
  displayName: 'pytest'
```

And then add the publish test result task.

```
- task: PublishTestResults@2
  condition: succeededOrFailed()
  inputs:
    testResultsFormat: 'JUnit'
    testResultsFiles: '**/test-*.xml'
    testRunTitle: 'Publish test results for Python $(python.version)'
```

Comment: Added the update on why the `docker cp` solution is not ideal. We actually have this solution in place and we were looking for an alternative solution so that we can see linewise coverage.